# Сохранение информации классов в файл

Tags: python

Требуется записать информацию об классах в блокнот. Не догоняю как сделать, пробовал создавать отдельную функцию для каждого класса, но не получилось.

```
class iComputer():
    def __init__(self, freq, core, val_RAM, val_HW):
        self.freq = freq
        self.core = core
        self.val_RAM = val_RAM
        self.val_HW = val_HW

    def showParams(self):
        print("Params of main PC:\n" + "Frequence is " + str(self.freq)  +"\nCore is " + str(self.core) +  "\nValue of RAM is " + str(self.val_RAM) + "\nValue of HW is " + str(self.val_HW))
    def iPower(self):
        print("\nPower of PC is", (self.freq * self.core * self.val_RAM))

mainPC = iComputer(4.3, 8, 16, 512)
mainPC.showParams()
mainPC.iPower()

class iNoteBook(iComputer):
    def __init__(self, freq, core, val_RAM, val_HW, dispSize, weight, keyLight, valUsb):
        super().__init__(freq, core, val_RAM, val_HW)
        self.dispSize = dispSize
        self.weight = weight
        self.keyLight = keyLight
        self.valUsb = valUsb
    def showParams(self):
        print("\nParams of NoteBook:" + "Frequence is " + str(self.freq)  +"\nCore is " + str(self.core) +  "\nValue of RAM is " + str(self.val_RAM) + "\nValue of HW is " + str(self.val_HW) + "\nDisplay size is " + self.dispSize + "\nWeight is " + str(self.weight) + "\nKey lightning " + self.keyLight + "\nNumber of usb is " + str(self.valUsb))
    def iPower(self):
        print("\nPower of NoteBook is", (self.freq * self.core * self.val_RAM))


noteBook = iNoteBook(2.2, 4, 8, 256, "1920x1080", 2, "No", 3)
noteBook.showParams()
noteBook.iPower()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398022/looping-over-all-member-variables-of-a-class-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавить метод для записи в класс.

Вот пример для класса `iComputer`:

```
class iComputer():
    def __init__(self, freq, core, val_RAM, val_HW):
        self.freq = freq
        self.core = core
        self.val_RAM = val_RAM
        self.val_HW = val_HW

    def tofile(self, path):
        info = "Frequence is {}\n\nCore is {}\n\nValue of RAM is {}\n\nValue of HW is {}".format(self.freq, self.core, self.val_RAM, self.val_HW)
        with open(path, 'w') as f:
            f.write(info)

x = iComputer(2.2, 4, 8, 256)

x.tofile('file.txt') #вместо file.txt вставить свой путь к файлу txt
```

Для класса iNoteBook определить такой же метод только со своими аргументами.

Answer (score 0):

Объявите в родительском классе вот такую функцию

```
def __str__(self) :
    members = {attr: getattr(self, attr) for attr in dir(self) if not callable(getattr(self, attr)) and not attr.startswith("__")}
    return self.__class__.__name__+ ' ' + members.__str__()
```

и теперь, если

```
noteBook = iNoteBook(2.2, 4, 8, 256, "1920x1080", 2, "No", 3)
print(noteBook)
```

в результате вы получите

```
iNoteBook {'core': 4, 'dispSize': '1920x1080', 'freq': 2.2, 'keyLight': 'No', 'valUsb': 3, 'val_HW': 256, 'val_RAM': 8, 'weight': 2}
```

если нужно сохранять в файл, можно функцию переименовать, а можно брать

`noteBook .__str__()`